# Custom Validation Message For User Model In Strapi

Tags: strapi

For unique fields, Strapi is sending the response:

```
{ message: `This ${field} is already taken` }
```

I want to change the error message for unique `username`

Answer (score 3):

the error message is handled by the Mongoose and Bookshelf queries of Users & Permissions plugin on create function.

[image]

To custom the message for `username` field, you will have to make a condition on it.

```
const field = _.words(_.last(message).split('_')[0]);
const error = { message: `This ${field} is already taken`, field };
if (field === 'username') {
  error.message = 'My custom message'
}
```

Comment: How i can integrate this without modifying the plugin code?

Comment: For now it's not possible. There is no way to customize with out hard coding in plugin code.

We have many feedback about that, we plan to had an hook système to add custom logic in specific place in core and plugins.

So the solution I write is the only way to do what you want to do.

Comment: A hook system will be really helpful, it will make the life of plugin developers much easier.

Comment: Completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still has this error and still using Strapi v3: You can achieve custom field validations in Strapi v3 with the following steps:

1. Copy `node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js` to `extensions/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js` to your project
2. Locate the existing Duplicate/taken pre-saving validation code in the register function:

```html
const user = await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne({
  email: params.email,
});

if (user && user.provider === params.provider) {
  return ctx.badRequest(
    null,
    formatError({
      id: 'Auth.form.error.email.taken',
      message: 'Email is already taken.',
    })
  );
}

if (user && user.provider !== params.provider && settings.unique_email) {
  return ctx.badRequest(
    null,
    formatError({
      id: 'Auth.form.error.email.taken',
      message: 'Email is already taken.',
    })
  );
}
```

3. Add / customize pre-saving validation checks here, rather than adjusting the post-saving db error reporting code down below in the register function (as it can give no field information and has to guess):

```html
const userWithEmail = await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne({
  email: params.email,
});

if (userWithEmail && userWithEmail.provider === params.provider) {
  return ctx.badRequest(
    null,
    formatError({
      id: 'Auth.form.error.email.taken',
      message: 'Email is already taken.',
    })
  );
}

// FYI to explain the second email check - why are there two dupliate email checks?
// The provider param and double check here is
// checking no duplicate users exist with other login providers
// (if you have "One account per email address" option enabled in backend).
if (userWithEmail && userWithEmail.provider !== params.provider && settings.unique_email) {
  return ctx.badRequest(
    null,
    formatError({
      id: 'Auth.form.error.email.taken',
      message: 'Email is already taken.',
    })
  );
}

// The new custom validation check with custom message.
// Here we ensure no users with duplicate username exists
const userWithUsername = await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne({
  username: params.username,
});

if (userWithUsername) {
  return ctx.badRequest(
    null,
    formatError({
      id: 'Auth.form.error.username.taken',
      message: 'Username is already taken!',
    })
  );
}
```